# Embedded signing missing image in footer

Tags: docusignapi

In the embedded signing iFrame, there is an image included at the bottom of the interface:

https://www.docusign.net/Member/Images/logo_poweredby_blue@2x.png

I'm guessing there's a 2x image script for Retina displays, but that image does not exist and is showing as a broken image:

[image: screenshot]

This is less of a question and more of a report.  Users using Retina Macbook Pro laptops are seeing a broken image at the bottom of the contract.

Comment: Are you using any branding settings through your DocuSign Console Preferences?  That might be one of the images that you can control through a custom brand profile.  Also, what device and O.S. are you testing on?

Comment: This is an item you can not change on the branding settings (yes, I've tried) -- I am on a Retina MacBook Pro. It's definitely something on the DocuSign end, as it's in the iFrame and there's a security sandbox that does not allow cross-domain frame interaction. It's DocuSign's default branding, and it's broken because there's a script (most likely a 2x / Retina quality image JS library -- see http://retinajs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine for me when I test Embedded Signing.  I'm testing on Chrome on a normal Mac Book Pro (i.e. not retina display), so I'm wondering if that's causing your issue.  When I test on my MBP I see the following.

[image]

What happens if you test on a different device, do you get the same results?

Comment: As I said before it is most definitely a retina issue. But there's a script that is being run on the DocuSign end of things that is going through and appending @2x to the end of the file name. Your regular MBP isn't going to trigger the replacement.

Comment: Ok this issue has been verified on our side and a fix submitted, which should be out for the September release (releases usually come out during the first week of each month)